# Merge Selenium projects

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testcase, selenium-ide, google-chrome

I need help about how to merge two projects into one in Selenium IDE tool for Google Chrome?

For example, when I test a part of an application and my friend tests another part of the same application, at the end we want to combine these projects into one project.

We tried to combine them in GitHub but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do yo mean when you say "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 4):

Selenium IDE has no version control integration, at least for now.

All the test info is written in a `.side` file (unless you are using [code export](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export) to another language).

If you've set up git correctly, you should be OK, provided you are not trying to work at the same file at the same time. Just commit different tests in folders you agreed on.

However, I don't think Selenium IDE is intended for large projects with multiple testers. It seems more adapt for quick and dirty checks or short test scripts.